# Pass custom data into datetime axis labels formatter

Tags: highcharts

It is quite easy to pass custom data into tooltip formatter by simply adding additional property for each series data item.

But I can't seem to find a way to pass property into xAxis.labels.formatter without using global scoped variables.

Currently I need to pass a string which will help me with custom formatting of label in future.

Anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a custom property in labels options object. Actually you can define a property wherever you want, but I assume this place fits the most.

In a formatter callback you can access to it via `this.axis.options.labels['customProperty']`.

```
xAxis: {
        categories: ['Foo', 'Bar', 'Foobar'],

        labels: {
            formatter: function () {
                    return this.value + ' ' + this.axis.options.labels.myString;
            },

            myString: 'myString'
        }
    },
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/0o4xe4rb/

Comment: How do you change `myString` after the chart data is updated?